# Setting initial text for validation message

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm currently using `ValidationMessageFor` to locate and display any errors in my asp.net MVC3 form. To provide this on a client-side level, I'm also using JQuery's unobtrusive validation.

These methods are fantastic but they seem to be lacking one thing - an option to display an initial 'hint' when the user is in a form field, just like on [Twitter's sign up form](https://twitter.com/signup). To clarify, I'd like this to appear in the same place as the validation message.

Can anyone tell me if this functionality is available and if not, how I would go about implementing it?

Comment: take a look at this, should solve your problem: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824124/html5-placeholders-with-net-mvc-3-razor-editorfor-extension

Comment: Thank you @anthonyvscode. However, am I not correct in thinking this will display as a placeholder within the textbox? I'm looking for the 'hint' to display where the ValidationMessage would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just elaborating on my comment above

The way I implemented this was by creating a "HintFor" html extension

```
public static MvcHtmlString HintFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> self, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    dynamic attribute = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, self.ViewData);
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(attribute.Description);
}
```

which just displays what you set the description property on the Display attribute for that viewmodel property

```
[Display(Name = "Application Title", Description = "Description goes in here")]
public string Title { get; set; }
```

Then in my front end I formatted each form step as shown (the extra classes are because I'm using the uni-form library to format my form)

```
        <div class="question">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title, new { @class = "label" })
            <div class="formHint">
                @Html.HintFor(m => m.Title)
            </div>
            <div class="response">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { @class = "textInput", autocomplete = "off" })
            </div>
            <div class="sidetip">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Title, null, new { @class = "invalid" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Then using a little CSS I set the "formhint" class to display none when the error message is shown

```
.validation-summary-valid, .field-validation-valid
{
    display: none;
}

.input-validation-error + .formHint
{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Hope this helps