# Extending HTML Helper

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

The code I am looking to produce is similar to:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
</div>
```

Using something like this:

```
@Html.LabelledTextBoxFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
```

Where the label text get derived from model.EmailAddress

This would be done using Data Annotation e.g.

```
[Displayname("Email Address]
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Will this affect the auto generated client side JS validation using jquery val?

Comment: do you want to manipulate label with javascript?

Comment: No i want to extend the C# Html helper

Comment: There is already a display attribute for this http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am aware of that, but the question states that i want to be able to create the above HTML, using a HTML helper e.g just saying with the razor page @Html.LabelledTextBoxFor(model => model.EmailAddress) which would then go in to the model class pull that data annotation for the name, create the id based on the model property name.

Comment: I see, I will provide you a sample

Answer (score 5):

I wrote an extension method, maybe this might help:

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelledTextBoxFor<TModel, TResult>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression)
{
    ExpressionType type = expression.Body.NodeType;
    if (type == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
    {
       MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression) expression.Body;
       var propName = memberExpression.Member.Name;

       var member = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;

       var attributes = member.GetCustomAttributes();

       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       foreach (var attribute in attributes)
       {
           if (attribute is DisplayAttribute)
           {
               DisplayAttribute d = attribute as DisplayAttribute;
               var displayName = d.Name;
               sb.Append("<div class=\"form-group\">");
               sb.AppendFormat("<label for=\"{0}\">{1}</label>", propName, displayName);
               sb.AppendFormat(
                        "<input type=\"email\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"{0}\" placeholder=\"Enter email\">",
                        propName);
               sb.Append("</div>");
               return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
             }
         }

     }
       return MvcHtmlString.Create("");
 }
```

You can use default display attribute to specify display name.There is no need for custom attributes.And you can use this extension like this:

```
@Html.LabelledTextBoxFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
```

Note: I have tried myself and it is working correctly.

Update: More simple version

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelledTextBoxFor2<TModel, TResult>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression)
    {
        ExpressionType type = expression.Body.NodeType;
        if (type == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
        {
            var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
            var displayName = metadata.DisplayName;
            var propName = metadata.PropertyName;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.Append("<div class=\"form-group\">");
            sb.AppendFormat("<label for=\"{0}\">{1}</label>", propName, displayName);
            sb.AppendFormat(
                        "<input type=\"email\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"{0}\" placeholder=\"Enter email\">",
                        propName);
             sb.Append("</div>");
             return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create("");
    }
```

Comment: +1, but you can simplify: `var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression( expression, helper.ViewData );`. This will give you an abstraction containing info such as display name.

Comment: right, I have used it before.anyway I just wanted to make sure this property has a display property.I have updated my answer with simplified version

Answer (score 1):

I would use `@Html.EditorFor` template. So create EditorTemplates folder in **Views/Shared** in your MVC project with a name **EmailAddress.cshtml** - it will display this template for every `[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]` defined in your model.

So: **EmailAddress.cshtml** should look sth like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="email">@Html.LabelFor(x => x)</label>
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark })
</div>
```

Model should look like this:

```
public class SomeModel {

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name="Some string for LabelFor", Prompt = "Placeholder in input"]
    public string SomeEmail { get; set; }
}
```

Note here, that I've used Prompt property of Display metadata, which I linked to placeholder via `ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark` in `EmailAddress.cshtml`.
`Html.LabelFor` will always take property Name from Display and DataType is needed for linking between EditorTemplates and model property.

And invoke all this "magic" by using

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.SomeEmail)
```

on a page, where you use `SomeMode` model.

I hope this does make sense.

Answer (score 1):

No need to reinvent the wheel. Check out [TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/).

The code you'd be writing would look similar to the below:

```
@Html.Bootstrap().FormGroup().TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailAddress).Placeholder("Enter email")
```

---

Disclaimer:
I'm the authot of TwitterBootstrapMVC.

TwitterBootstrapMVC for use on Bootstrap 3 is not free. See details on the website.

Comment: The thing is, It must be free due to the nature of the project

Answer (score 0):

The Data Annotations go in the viewmodel above the property:

```
[DisplayName("Email Address")]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

Then, in your view, you'd have something like this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress, new { @placeholder="Enter email", @class="form-control", @id="email" })
```

Comment: Which i understand, As mentioned above the main problem is dont want to have to do both @Html.LabelFor and TextBox for.

I would like to make my own HTML helper which combines both of these and wraps them in a DIV, To match the given code in the question.

I know it sounds silly the now but if you think about it once i get this working i will be able to integrate bootstrap and C# alot easier.

Comment: Ah, well I believe there are already answers for this.  Have you looked at this one yet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824124/html5-placeholders-with-net-mvc-3-razor-editorfor-extension