# How do the MVC html helpers use expressions to get an objects property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, expression

For example:

```
Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ModelProperty)
```

If I were to get an expression like this as a method argument, how would I get the referenced property from the expression? My experience with expressions is somewhat limited and based on what I know, I don't get how this works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get property name easily like this:

```
var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
var propName = metadata.PropertyName;
```

Or you can get property and its attributes:

```
MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression) expression.Body;
var member = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
var attributes = member.GetCustomAttributes();
```

For example you can write a simple method that generates a input element like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextboxForCustom<TModel, TResult>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
        var propName = metadata.PropertyName;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("<input type=\"text\" id=\"{0}\" />", propName);

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());

    }
```

Take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007550/extending-html-helper/21008006#21008006) here.

Answer (score 9):

I once wrote my own `EditorFor`, it had the following definition:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyHtmlEditorFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> h, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
  // ...
}
```

To get the information of the property I used the [ModelMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) class:

```
ModelMetadata m = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, h.ViewData);
var value = m.Model;
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you say `var value`, but call out the type of `m` explicitly rather than just `var m`, especially when the type of `m` is obvious?

Comment: because Model could be any object...  he could of been vary specific or used object also.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I added that line as an example in my answer, in reality I did some checks on the type before casting it to an explicit type.

Comment: I used MVC html helpers as an example of where I have seen this used.