# How can I use placeholder attribute with Html.EditorFor?

Tags: asp.net, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, placeholder

I want to use the placeholder attribute in the Html.EditorFor so I did just like in the first answer: [Html5 Placeholders with .NET MVC 3 Razor EditorFor extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824124/html5-placeholders-with-net-mvc-3-razor-editorfor-extension)

But in the final part, I don't have the EditorTemplates folder so I created it and when I tried to create the string.cshtml view I couldn't because the name "string" is reserved so I chose stringg.cshtml instead and it didn't work! Do I have to change the name elsewhere in my program? I did exactly like the answer...

Thank you!

Answer (score 65):

Upgrade to MVC 5.1 and you can use HTML attributes in EditorFor:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.variable, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Your Placeholder Text" } })
```

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes

Comment: +1 - Thank you for that link. I would say this is your best option if you're willing to upgrade to 5.1. Works great.

Comment: Why did you have to use `@` before the `placeholder` attribute?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but that's how it's done. When you enumerate htmlAttributes you need to use @ for them to be recognized. (@class, @id ...)

Comment: @Yoda @Medo `@` is not necessary in this case. `@` is used only if variable name is the same as any of the C# keywords, i.e. `@class`.

Answer (score 18):

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.members_ssn, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Your Example Here" } })
```

Comment: Do you mind taking a few minutes and explain what your code is doing?

Answer (score 7):

This works for MVC 5.

In my case i was looking to set the placeholder from the model metadata, like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.name) } })
```

Answer (score 4):

When using `TextBoxFor` or `TextAreaFor` rather than `EditorFor`, use only the inner key-value pair from @Medo's answer, since the method directly expects an htmlAttributes object:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.variable, new { placeholder = "Your Placeholder Text" })
```

(I realize this is tangential to the original question, but having this here would have helped me when I landed on this page earlier, looking for an answer to how to add placeholder text to an `Html.TextAreaFor`!)

Answer (score 0):

Use some jquery, eg:
    $("#FirstName").attr("placeholder", "Do not type name - use Search button");