# How to use the placeholder in mvc for the editorfor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to use placeholder in @Html.EditorFor for text in mvc. I tried many of things even search in google but whatever the answer I got that not work. I surprised...!!!. And finally I ask in question.

My lastest code for placeholder is

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ToEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Your EmailID...!!!" } })
```

This code also not work.

Thank You.

Comment: The code is right. this should give you the desired output.

Comment: @Kumar_Vikas Thats why I surprised that why it is not working.

Comment: maybe the problem is with mvc version https://stackoverflow.com/a/23478509/3467213

Comment: @pryashrma may be.

Comment: Even i think so. I tried your code and its working.

Comment: @Kumar_Vikas may be its is the problem of mvc version  stackoverflow.com/a/23478509/3467213

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use placeholder attribute with Html.EditorFor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23455043/how-can-i-use-placeholder-attribute-with-html-editorfor)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as yours, below code worked for me in my project:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ToEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new {placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(m=>m.ToEmail) } })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add HTML attributes you should use `@HTML.TextBoxFor` instead of `EditorFor` and bind value from value attribute i.e.

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ToEmail, new {  @value = model.ToEmail, @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Your EmailID...!!!"  })
```

Comment: Never set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods.