# Placeholder in MVC 4 model or view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-placeholder

I am trying to set place holder to textbox or multi line text box in MVC 4. So far it is not working.

```
[Display(Name = "Location", Prompt = "Enter info related to Location")]
public string LocationDesc { get; set; }
```

And the View as below

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LocationDesc , new { placeholder = "Enter info related to Location" })
```

Place holder just need to show some information and I am happy to display it anywhere (View or model)

We are using MVC4.

Cheers

Comment: Instead of editorfor use textareafor..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Placeholder attribute on `@Html.EditorFor()` in asp.net mvc,there are two solutions for your problem :

1.) You can make a custom attribute for  `@Html.EditorFor()` a great article on this is there on stackoverflow link :- [Html5 Placeholders with .NET MVC 3 Razor EditorFor extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824124/html5-placeholders-with-net-mvc-3-razor-editorfor-extension) and you can visit this link also  [http://aspadvice.com/blogs/kiran/archive/2009/11/29/Adding-html-attributes-support-for-Templates-*2D00*-ASP.Net-MVC-2.0-Beta_2D00_1.aspx](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/kiran/archive/2009/11/29/Adding-html-attributes-support-for-Templates-_2D00_-ASP.Net-MVC-2.0-Beta_2D00_1.aspx)

2.) Instead of `@Html.EditorFor()` you can use `@Html.TextAreaFor()`

Comment: Worked without any exception! Cheers