# Placeholder in @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name) in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I used `[prompt("name")]` in Controller and

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email,
new {placeholder=ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark})`
```

in view but nothing showed
I also used help of [Html5 Placeholders with .NET MVC 3 Razor EditorFor extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824124/html5-placeholders-with-net-mvc-3-razor-editorfor-extension)
but nothing happened 
I need Placeholder for @EditorFor not for Textbox
Any Help Appreciated

Comment: Whats wrong with a textbox? what type of controls are you trying to generate? For MVC-5 you can use `Html.EditorFor(m => m.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = ... }, })`

Comment: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Enter the title Here" } }) I already wrote that but nothing getting

Comment: In MVC-5? You have tagged it both MVC-4 and MVC-5! But why not `TextBoxFor()`?

Comment: see default scaffolding generated @EditorFor for all attributes for a model

Comment: I assume you mean properties, not attributes. but why not just change it to `TextBoxFor()` (add `type="email"` if required)

Comment: Thanks , I changed to TextBoxFor() as you said

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Actually, you need MVC 5.1, not MVC5 for htmlAttribute support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EditorFor doesn't accept HtmlAttribut argument you have to use TextBoxFor instead of it ;)
try this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new  {placeholder=ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark})`
```

Comment: Thanks But do you know why this is so for `@EditoreFor ` ? @TRIKI Khaled

Comment: the Html.EditorFor works with different types and would generate an Html input elements with different types according to the type of the attribut you've entred as argument.
you can check the classes and see check differences between both of them : EditorExtensions and InputExtensions

Comment: As of MVC 5.1, EditorFor can handle HtmlAttributes.  This was one of the added features.

Answer (score 5):

You can write HTML attributes into `Html.EditorFor` using the following syntax. Make sure you use @ before class and placeholder so that the renderer knows this is HTML markup.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { 
    htmlAttributes = new { 
        @class = "form-control", 
        @placeholder = "Email Address"
    }
})
```

Comment: Typically only reserved keywords like `class` require the `@` prefix in an `htmlAttributes` object, "placeholder" is fine without it. Not always consistent though; strangely, setting a "value" isn't parsed as a reserved word but requires using proper case (`@Value`) to be applied correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Work for me just with TextBoxFor.

```
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.emailContact, new {@placeholder = "Your Placeholder Text" }
```